# How WCS's SolR can index Magnolia's content

Tags: solr, websphere, magnolia, websphere-commerce

I'm trying to find a way to index Magnolia's content with a Solr from an other CMS.
(It's not realy a CMS but it's like. I'm talking about websphere commece 7 FEP5).

I've a Solr engine, plugged in a DB2 database, and already configured to index the content of that database.
Now, I have to plug a Magnolia CMS, (with is own database). And one of the requirement is to be able to display search results (provided from my Solr), and theses search result must include Magnolia's content.

Does anybody have any ideas to do that?

Using a second Solr system (the one into Magnolia) is not really acceptable.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Regards,
Dekx.

Comment: Is this unstructured content that you are hosting within the WCS domain, or at least on a web page somewhere in your domain?

Comment: Yes, look like something like that. I'm looking on the infocenter about the unstructured content and the crawler. I will update my post if it resolve my problem. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you should be able to do what you want using the WCS unstructured content crawler.

Start here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/csdmanagesearchsitecontent.htm